# Push to all arrays if value doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to look if **every** field readBy doesn't contain "me" value, if it's the case I want to push "me" to **every** readBy. [Here's the playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j4r_ssMrDev), as you can see it only push to the first occurrence where "me" doesn't exist. What am I missing ?

I want an output like this :

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "forum": [
      {
        "msg": "Hi",
        "readBy": [
          "me",
          "you"
        ]
      },
      {
        "msg": "How are you?",
        "readBy": [
          "me"
        ]
      },
      {
        "msg": "Fine, thank you",
        "readBy": ["me"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I know I could do it with `$addToSet` but I'd like to do it in a "cleaner" way

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution with `arrayFilters` option : https://mongoplayground.net/p/-HFjeblsjLT please comment if you think of another way to achieve it